# Respond to ICMP while having multiple local tables in Linux

Tags: networking, routing, iptables, iproute2

I have an IP range and I want to listen on all IP addresses, assume that is `10.0.0.0/8`
Using TPROXY and packet mark I can respond to TCP traffic. This range should be in local table, but I don't want outbound traffic responded locally, so I created another table (say table 10) and added local route in that table.

```
ip route add local 10.0.0.0/8 dev lo table 10
ip rule add fwmark 1 lookup 10
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j TPROXY --on-port 80 --on-ip 127.0.0.1 --tproxy-mark 0x1/0x1
```

Now I need to respond ICMP messages for this range, so I added this iptables rule:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -p icmp -d 10.0.0.0/8 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
```

But after adding this rule machine gets ICMP packets but responds nothing, acting as blackhole

What am I doing wrong?

**Update:**
I tried sending outbound traffic to this table, but I got `connect: Network is unreachable` when I ping it and I believe these are related.
Try these commands to reproduce it

```
ip route add local 10.0.0.0/8 dev lo table 10
ip rule add to 10.0.0.0/8 lookup 10
ping 10.0.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

TPROXY is intended for intercepting *routed* traffic (and with tinkering even doing it on a bridge). It can [handle TCP or UDP, but not ICMP](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/tree/net/netfilter/xt_TPROXY.c?h=v5.10#n214).

OP hints that the system is a final node receiving traffic rather than a router. Then all these complex settings that don't even achieve the goal are not needed.

Remove all previous alterations (*iptables*, *ip rule*, *ip route* ...) and do only this:

```
ip route add local 10.0.0.0/8 dev lo table local
```

End.

If one would prefer the use of a separate table to avoid alterations to the *local* table, this can be done instead:

```
ip route add local 10.0.0.0/8 dev lo table 10
ip rule add preference 10 lookup 10
```

Or even just this (adding it in the *main* table instead):

```
ip route add local 10.0.0.0/8 dev lo
```

Just be careful about other routing rules added later for other features (especially if not using the keyword `preference`) so this route stays evaluated among the first.

Wherever the route is added, if the *lo* interface is brought down then up (which seldom happens for *lo*), this route will disappear and will have to be added back. `

In the end:

- no TPROXY needed
- no mark needed
- no NAT needed
- not having to ponder how Strict Reverse Path Forwarding and `rp_filter` behave in presence of a mark
- no need for an application to use any IP_TRANSPARENT socket option to use this range of addresses as source: the route matters, not the fact that an address was added anywhere (it wasn't).